# The difference between using a comma or a full stop

Tags: meaning, commas, sentence, expression-choice

What's the difference between "I see, I see" and "I see. I see"? Can one use a comma in between?

The first sentence could be used in formal writing, right?

What about this one: "My house, my rules" instead of "My house. My rules"? What's the difference between these two sentences and are both grammatically correct?

Comment: Makes for a good question on ELL http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Comment: You can construct a similar question there, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a period or 'full stop' signals the end of a sentence, i.e., a complete statement or idea that is independent.

> "I see. I see"

Two individual sentences. Two thoughts. That they are identical is merely incidental. Here it is either a simple repetition or, esp. in speech, depending on intonation, a very different pair of ideas conveyed.

> "I see, I see"

One sentence. One thought. The second occurrence reinforces ("Have no doubt, I confirm."), modifies, (per intonation, cf. above) or restates differently to complete the expression.

The reasoning is more reflective in the second example.

> "My house, my rules" vs. "My house. My rules"

Comment: Can anyone give me an example of 'I see, I see' and 'I see. I see' being used that portrays the differences in the meaning?

Comment: @user36521 You need to do some background research and bring it to the table.

Comment: The thing is, to me 'I see, I see' does seem like it can be two thoughts as well.

Comment: @user36521 Yes, two, but not independent of each other, which is all that grammar can assert. Beyond that any implications are in the domain of writing and literature.

Comment: Background research for a usage example?

Comment: And are both grammatically correct and can be used in formal writing?

Comment: I can see how 'My house. My rules' shows two independent sentences when it comes to the technical side of writing, but I don't see how they are independent when it comes to the overall meaning of the two sentences together.

Comment: Yes. And yes. Can you tell us why you think they may not be?

Comment: 'My house, my rules' are fragmented sentences, so I wouldn't think they would go in formal writing. Would they? As for 'I see, I see' perhaps it would seem informal because the second phrase of it is redundant?

Comment: @user36521 Explain your thoughts completely and fully in the question, so others can see and understand your issues. Also, your feelings or mine have no relevance; grammar has set rules and its own limitations.

Comment: Feeling have no relevance to grammar? Can't say I agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

The two expressions are colloquial, and therefore likely to occur in writing only in informal contexts, or as a record of what someone has said. A comma before the repeated *I see*, will give the impression of continuous speech. On the other hand, a full stop (period) between *my house* and *my rules* will make the statement more emphatic.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are grammatically correct and the choice of which one to use would depend on context.

***I see, I see*** could mean anything from an absent-minded murmur of agreement to an irritated "Yes I understand, stop going on about it."

***I see. I see.*** The slight pause between them could mean you are acknowledging true understanding of something which is being explained to you. Or it could be angry, as in:

"I see. I see. You think you can behave exactly as you like and I'll still here be waiting for you! Well I won't!"

***My house, my rules*** is a statement that I am in charge because I pay the bills.

***My house. My rules*** is more emphatic, perhaps repeating it to someone who has broken a rule.

***My house! My rules!*** is a full blown argument often followed by "And if you don't like it you can pack your bags and get out!"

Answer (score 0):

'My house, my rules.' and 'My house. My rules.' are both correct, but the comma or full stop indicates slightly different use and pronunciation/inflection when speaking.